# Display all div attached to category in block when click button show more in jquery dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, dom

I have div displayed by category .In my case, I passed id for category in button show more

```
if ($custom_term->count > 2) {
                echo ("<div class='show-more' data-id='$current_category'>Show more</div>");

            }
```

But , in click show more button , only one div is displayed .I want to display all div

[image]

```
$(".show-more").click(function(){
var ids = $(this).attr("data-id");
$("#"+ids).css({"display": "block"});
});
```

I have categories .In each category I have custom posts. At initaillay, we displayed 2 posts for every category. In the category we have more than 2 posts add button show more .In click button show more, we display posts by 4. The two initial posts + 4 posts .In every click show more we display by 4 posts.All wordks , just the action show more , at now , we display only one posts , this is the problem
When show more is open in each category, we should close the other shoe more button

```
 <?php
        $custom_terms = get_terms('genre');

        foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            $postsPerPage = -1;
            $current_category = "";

            $args = [
                'post_type' => 'film',
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                'orderby' => 'id',
                'order' => 'ASC',


                'tax_query' => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $custom_term->slug,

                    ],
                ],
            ];

            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            $parent_included = false;
            if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                              echo '<h2 class="text-actualites">' . $custom_term->name . '</h2>';

                $counter = 0;
                //$count_posts = count($loop->have_posts());
                $i = 0;

                while ($loop->have_posts()) :

                    $loop->the_post();

                    $i++;

                    $img = get_field('image', "$post->ID");

                    $cat = $custom_term->term_id;
                    $current_category = $cat;

                    if ($custom_term->name == "Adventure") {
                    ?>

                     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                         <div class="card1 recrutements">
                             <div class="card-header">
                                 <div>
                                     <img src=<?php echo $img["url"]; ?> class='mymap-icon' alt=''>

                                 </div>


                                 <div>
                                     <span class="titre-recrutement">
                                         <div class="bnt-makers ">Communiqué de presse </div>
                                         <div> <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>


                                         <div class="bnt-maker "><?php the_field('nom', $post->ID); ?>
                                         </div>

                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="card-body">
                                 <p><?php the_field('description', $post->ID); ?> </p>

                                 <a class="dedcription-btn pop recrut" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                     <span class="name-descripeion">En savoir plus</span>
                                     <div class="btn-icon">
                                         <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                     </div>
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>


                    <?php
                    } else {
                        $counter++; 
                        if (!$parent_included) {
                           echo '<div id="parentId">';
                         
                           $parent_included = true;
                        }
                        
                ?>
                <div class="col-lg-16 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" class="content">
                         <?php
                            if ($counter <= 2) {
                                echo ("<div class='card recrutements'>");
                            } else {
                                echo ("<div class='card recrutements hide-block'  id='$cat'>");
                                //var_dump($cat); data-id='$cat'
                            }
                            ?>
                         <div class="card-header">
                             <div>
                                 <img src=<?php echo $img["url"]; ?> class='mymap-icon' alt=''>

                             </div>
                             <div>
                                 <span>
                                     <div><?php echo '<p>' . $custom_term->name . '</p>'; ?>
                                     </div>

                                     <div> <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>

                                     <div class="bnt-maker "><?php the_field('nom', $post->ID); ?>
                                     </div>

                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <p><?php the_field('description', $post->ID); ?> </p>

                             <a class="dedcription-btn pop recrut" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                 <span class="name-descripeion">En savoir plus</span>
                                 <div class="btn-icon">
                                     <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                 </div>
                             </a>
                         </div>
                        </div>
 </div>


 <?php
                    }
                endwhile;
                echo('</div>');
            }
           
            if ($custom_term->count > 2) {
               
                echo ("<div class='show-more' data-id='$current_category'>Show more</div>");
                

            }
        }
    ?>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

               var tax = ["89","93"];


                $(".show-more").click(function(){
                var ids = $(this).attr("data-id");
                $("#"+ids).css({"display": "block"});
               

                for(let i = 0; i < tax.length; i ++){

                    if(tax[i] != ids){
                    $("#"+tax[i]).css({"display": "none"});
                    }
                
                
                }
                
        });



});

   </script>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkz7D.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to change div structure

```
<?php
if ($custom_term->count > 2) {
 echo "<div class='show-more'>Show more</div>";
}
echo '<div class="cat-group" style="display:none">
for($current_category as $id)
{
    echo '<div id="cat-name" data-id="'.$id.'" style="display:none">category name</div>';
}
</div>';
?>
<script>
$(".show-more").click(function(){
$(".cat-group").each(function(){
  $(".cat-name").show();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I, try but still not working .The example like in picture added

Comment: For now, The categories are displayed correctly .Just, in click show more for category how have more than 2 posts, when I click show more, only one displayed. The 2 posts initially + 1 post when click show more .I want to display all posts for this category

Comment: You just need to change minor HTML and js otherwise code is almost working, you need to change you're for loop data and check your array it will be resolved.. I just give you a sample code

Comment: I added all code

Comment: I need help , I can't resolve it